# Visual studio вылетает во время работы

Tags: visual-studio-2017

У меня вылетает и автоматически перезагружается visual studio во время работы,что меня очень сильно раздражает. Происходит это когда я пишу программы в среде. Быть может, у кого-нибудь была подобная проблема. Я даже причины вылета не могу посмотреть, просто зависает и вылетает во время работы. (Visual studio 2017 Enterprice x64, компьютер работает под Windows 10 Professional x64)

Comment: Это не сайт разработчиков Visual Studio.

Comment: Так выдай скриншот краша, что знеачит когда пишу программы?Зайти зайпустить ты хоть ее можешь?